# File not found exception while starting Flume agent

Tags: hadoop, filenotfoundexception, flume, flume-ng

I have installed Flume for the first time. I am using hadoop-1.2.1 and flume 1.6.0

I tried setting up a flume agent by following [this guide](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html).

I executed this command : `$ bin/flume-ng agent -n $agent_name -c conf -f conf/flume-conf.properties.template`

It says `log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./logs/flume.log (No such file or directory)`

Isn't the `flume.log` file generated automatically? If not, how can I rectify this error ?

Comment: Check the permissions on the directory. If required, create an empty flume.log file.

Comment: where do I create that log file?

Comment: In the directory, from where you are executing the script

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mkdir ./logs
sudo chown `whoami` ./logs
bin/flume-ng agent -n $agent_name -c conf -f conf/flume-conf.properties.template
```

The first line creates the `logs` directory in the current directory if it does not already exist. The second one sets the owner of that directory to the current user (you) so that `flume-ng` running as your user can write to it.

Finally, please note that this is not the recommended way to run Flume, just a quick hack to try it.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error probably because you are running command directly on console, you've to first go to the bin in flume and try running your command there over console.

[image: This is the image for your reference]

Answer (score 0):

As @Botond says, you need to set the right permissions.

However, if you run Flume within a program, like supervisor or with a custom script, you might want to change the default path, as it's relative to the launcher. 
This path is defined in your */path/to/apache-flume-1.6.0-bin/conf/log4j.properties*. There you can change the line

```
flume.log.dir=./logs
```

to use an absolute path that you would like to use - you still need the right permissions, though.